# Clicking RadioButton crashes app

Tags: java, android

I have an app that allows the user to select from a list of RadioButtons and a DatePicker and displays output.  I got the app running in an emulator, and when I test the RadioButtons, the app crashes and the emulator says the "unfortunately the app has stopped."  I'm not sure why this is happening?

**EDIT - STACK TRACE**

StackTrace:

```
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onRadioButtonClicked(View) in the activity class edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.RadioButton with id 'radioButtonHoliday'
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onRadioButtonClicked [class android.view.View]
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3579)
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100) 
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
12-01 00:30:39.490 2007-2007/edu.wmich.lab4jvandyk5713 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT 2 - XML in question**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewUltimateParty"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgViewUltimateParty"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"/>
    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txtViewAppDescription"
            android:id="@+id/textViewAppDescription"
            android:contentDescription="@string/txtViewAppDescription"
            android:contextClickable="false" />
    </TableRow>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/rdoGroupParties"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupParties">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rdoButtonPajama"
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonPajama"
            android:contentDescription="@string/rdoButtonPajama"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rdoButtonPizza"
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonPizza"
            android:contentDescription="Pizza Party"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rdoButtonGraduation"
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonGraduation"
            android:contentDescription="@string/rdoButtonGraduation"
            android:contextClickable="false"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rdoButtonRetirement"
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonRetirement"
            android:contentDescription="@string/rdoButtonRetirement"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rdoButtonHoliday"
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonHoliday"
            android:contentDescription="@string/rdoButtonHoliday"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />
    </RadioGroup>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnChooseDate"
        android:id="@+id/buttonChooseDate" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:transitionGroup="false">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnNextStep"
        android:id="@+id/buttonNextStep"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btnNextStep" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewOutput"
        android:contentDescription="@string/txtViewOutput"
        android:layout_column="1" />
</TableRow>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Crash logs/stack trace please....

Comment: WHY WOULD YOU REMOVE ALL YOUR CODE? adding it back

Answer (score 2):

you need to define the method:

```
 public void onRadioButtonClicked(View v){
      //... some logic or nothing
 }
```

this method is attempting to be called since you define `android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"` in xml, therefore the click of the view expects a method in your activity called this which passes the `View` clicked as its only parameter.